# SolidWorks PDM drawing watermark when referencing older version?

Tags: solidworks, cad

How can you add a watermark on SolidWorks drawings/templates present when the drawing is not updated with the most recent part file? This would be very helpful in order to reduce production errors.

Comment: You may be overstating the importance of an automatic watermark and understating the importance of drawing review.  The old version was once the most recent, and there may be prints out there without the watermark.  One solution to that I've observed was to make the rev part of the number.  If scheduled to the new number, it announces there is a new rev!

Comment: ^This. Adding some automated watermark system (which would not be present on .PDFs) could create a false sense of security. You've got to check the drawing revision against the production BOM.